# Opening input type radio using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, addeventlistener, tabbed

I have a tabbed form using input type `radio` and want to use `addEventListener` to open a particular tab on click.

```js
document.getElementById("job_location").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("tab1").checked = true;
});
```

```html
 <a id="job_location" href="#map"><b><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"/>Location</b></a>

<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" />
<label for="tab1">My Location</label>

<task-section id="content1">
  <iframe style="width: 600;  height:450;" src="https://www.google.com/>
    </iframe>
</task-section>
```

The idea is that when someone clicks on the link with id `job_location`, the tab with id `tab1` will be clicked, revealing info in `content1`.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my JavaScript?

Comment: in your codes the container with id="content1" is automatically revealed..you want to hide this container and when either the radio box is clicked or the link is clicked the iframe is revealed?

Comment: actually content1 is not automatically revealed.  when the page loads, it is actually tab2 (content2) that is in view.  What I want is for content1 to be revealed once a user clicks on <a id="job_location" href = "#map">.

Comment: can you put in your question the html for 'content2' and any other related codes?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something... double quote after www.google.com

`src="https://www.google.com/` you've omitted the closing `"`

And to make your code work, try this

HTML

```
<a id="job_location" href = "#map"><b><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"/>Location</b></a>

<div id="tabs">
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs"/>
  <label for="tab1">My Location</label>

</div>

<task-section id="content1">
    <iframe style= "width: 600;  height:450;" src="https://www.google.com/">
</iframe>
</task-section>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("job_location").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("tabs").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("content1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("tab1").checked = true;
    });
```

CSS

```
#tabs, #content1{
  display: none;
}
```

[Check it out on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wisdomabioye/jv5p8a5a/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help.  this is very peculiar.  I've reproduced my code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yundlu/4h1rowdt/2/ and it appears to work perfectly.  I'm working in a ServiceNow environment and the same exact code won't work...not sure if this is specific to ServiceNow or not...